# Connection timed out Issue with TFVC in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, tfs, android-studio-3.0

I got following error from Android Studio 3.0 when I tried to Checkout a project from version control (TFVC).
I got this issue when I did following activities from Android Studio.
From menu Option : 
VCS-->Checkout From Version control-->Team Service TFVC (clicked on "Create work space" button and got this error).

> An error occurred: Connection timed out: connect
>
> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred: Connection timed out: connect
> ```
>
> at
>   com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.commands.Command.throwIfError(Command.java:402)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.commands.CreateWorkspaceCommand.throwIfError(CreateWorkspaceCommand.java:91)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.commands.CreateWorkspaceCommand.parseOutput(CreateWorkspaceCommand.java:73)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.commands.CreateWorkspaceCommand.parseOutput(CreateWorkspaceCommand.java:22)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.commands.Command$1.completed(Command.java:171)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.ToolRunner$ListenerProxy.completed(ToolRunner.java:295)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.ToolRunner$ProcessWaiter.run(ToolRunner.java:333)

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: are you using windows OS?

Comment: @ Samir Bhatt : Yes, Windows 10 and AS 3.0 , In server side : OS - Win server 2012 R2 , TFS 2017 , Visual studio 2017

Comment: It might be because of Firewall. Please check once. I am not sure but i faced this issue once because of firewall once.

Comment: @  Samir Bhatt : I checked , it's not related with Firewall

Comment: @rangarajb2005 have u found any solution for this???

Comment: @  BMM : No , trying to find a solution

Comment: Do you have an http proxy on your network? Are you going to check out of a large of items in the project?

Comment: Hi rangarajb2005, any update on this issue, have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

***Note:*** You must have the TF command line tool installed to be able to use TFVC features.  First make sure you have correctly configured this for Android studio. See [TFVC Setup Requirements](http://java.visualstudio.com/docs/tools/androidstudio#_tfvc-support) for TFVC support.

You could try below ways to narrow down the issue:

- If you have any proxy on your network,  move the proxy and try it
  again.
- Check out a single or two items instead of a whole project.
- Double check the **Event Log** in the TFS server machine to see if
  there are some error message helps.

As a workaround you could drop to the command line and create the workspace from there. Once the workspace is created, then check out files instead of select "create workspace"  when  using the "Checkout flow".

Also take a look this [demo of the TFVC features](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=va5rM5ZaXIg&feature=youtu.be) shows how to use Android Studio Plugin with TFVC.